# What should be table structure to maintain login logout logs?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, database-table

I have loginlog table as following

```
Field       Type
login_id    int(10)     NOT NULL
platform    varchar(50) NOT NULL
browser     varchar(50) NOT NULL
ipaddress   varchar(50) NOT NULL
last_login  datetime    NULL
last_logout datetime    NULL
```

But on this structure I am confuse that I can add login time but its hard to update it for logout time. I have not added primary key because logs are frequent and primarykey will soon reach it max value. What should be the best way? Please help.

Comment: "and primarykey will soon reach it max value" -- if this is an issue, you have larger problems.

Comment: `INT` can store up to `2147483647` different values. Even if you logged in and out once a second you would need 68 years until your login_id runs out of ids. If you run into this problem, just update it to `BIGINT` or clear the logs. `BIGINT` supports up to `9223372036854775807` ids. Even a million users logging in and out once a second will be busy ~300'000 years to reach your new limit.

Comment: Why dont you add `session_id` as a field and when logging out, update the logout with the corresponding session id. This will solve the multiple simultaneous logins on different browsers/machines also.

Answer (score 7):

Having a single row with both login and logout like that is just asking for trouble, because it assumes that every login has a corresponding logout, which is just not the case. Sometimes they will login on a public computer and never log out, sometimes they will open an anonymous window and login.

Instead, I would cut it down to just a type:

- login_id
- platform
- browser
- ip_address
- date
- type (login / logout)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create table logout log, with 2 columns.
with a reference to corresponding login_id, and the time of logout.

And last_login, and last_logout do not make sense to me, but your logic may require it. Because IMO you should avoid having columns, which can have NULL.

**EDIT:** As a addon, I would say why would you accumulate so much data. If it is **only** for analyzing user's browser, platform, you can use Google Analytics. And you can just keep last_login, and last_logout for each user, then. Again, your business logic may require it.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is that if you want information of last log in and last log out only then.... make the user_id as primary key... and just change that information instead add new record... you can add one count field to enhance your functionality... to get number of count the person is log in...

and if you want each and every login data... just go with the serialization concept... it will help... make array set count as key and your last login, logout, browser as a value of array...serialize that and store in database...

Comment: I need to log each login entry on daily basis

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to update entry for each user once he/she relogins to avoid primary key reaching its max value.

Comment: see basti's comment under the post. Reaching the max value for the primary key is not a realistic concern and if you do want to design around it, all you have to do is specify a larger int type.